# Where can i download spatio-temporal landslide station based dataset for india in .csv format

Tags: geospatial, weather, research, india

Looking for landslide spatio-temporal station based dataset for India or Global region. Need to analyze the characteristics of landslide attributes such as soil type, slope aspect, date, latitude, longitude, Date/time, rainfall and climatic factors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the OpenData SE

Comment: Kindly suggest me answer for above question...